# passing argument from bash file to php (long string with spaces)

Tags: php, linux, bash

I want to pass a text as a argument from a bash file to a php script like this:

**bash script**

```
#!/bin/sh

php /var/www/html/assets/sms/get_sms.php $SMS_1_NUMBER $SMS_1_TEXT
```

**php script**

```
<?php

$url = "http://localhost/user/user/get_sms/".$argv[1];    
$postdata = array('number' => $argv[1],'text'=>$argv[2]);
do_post_request($url,$postdata);

function do_post_request($url, $postdata)
{
  //My function
}
?>
```

The problem is that, the first argument to the bash file is a number but the second argument is text.  The Php file which receives the arguments just takes the first string of the text. For example, if the text of the $SMS_1_TEXT variable is "How can I make it work" , the php file will receive only "How".

How can I make it woks better?

Thank you very much

Comment: Btw: `sh` (Bourne shell) is not usually `bash` (Bourne-again shell).

Answer (score 3):

Quoting. Replace `$SMS_1_TEXT` by `"$SMS_1_TEXT"`.

Comment: Dont do that. Use escapeshellarg() instead.

Comment: Oops, your right. If string contains double quotes then these will need escaping.

Comment: @maxhb you are coming from the wrong direction. He wants to go from a shell script to a PHP script. The other way round you would be right, but for this situation Cyrus's solution is correct.